# Materialize view refresh when its on NEED_COMPILE state

Tags: database, oracle, database-performance, materialized-views

I'm a fresh bee for DB. 
We have large set of Materialize-view in our prod server. All the views are being refreshed manually on every 3 hours in a stored proc through a job.

Had a problem over the past couple of weeks when the MV refresh happens, DB went to Peek IO operation. CPU utilization turned heavy caused slowness.

Later we noticed, due to some DML/DDL operations in the past on core tables, Most of the MV is turned NEED_COMPILE state. When the actual refresh happens with this state, found "object not found" error logged.

Please advise me to connecting the dots to understand the problem,

- Is this situation can cause peek IO operation?
- What will happen to MV logs when the MV itself is in NEED_COMPILE
  state?
- Does MV logs cause the IO operation Peek when the actual MV is in NEED_COMPILE state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition to NEEDS_COMPILE status is an expected behaviour when you perform a DML/DDL operation on the master tables. Using "REFRESH ON COMMIT" you are getting a different behaviour because those MVs are refreshed at the same time as the DML. In that status the materialized view can be read, but of course the updated records cannot be seen. As for the performance problems be sure the MV logs are properly indexed (index on M_ROW$$ and XID$$ are usually needed, where XID$$ replaces SNAPTIME$$ since Oracle 11gR2). More indexes might be needed to improve performance. As for the "object not found" error, you must submit details on Oracle version and the exact log you get.